# Why is my session['username'] is always the last entry from my database instead of current one in flask?

Tags: python, html, database, flask

I got the simplest db:

```
class users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column('username', db.String(100))
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(100))
```

here are my login, register, user and logout functions:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        found_pass = users.query.filter_by(password=password).first()
        if found_user and found_pass:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash("You've just logged in!")
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Data. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        session['username'] = username
        session['password'] = password
        found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if found_user:
            flash("User already registered!")
        elif not request.form['username'] or not request.form['password']:
            flash("Enter valid data!")
        else:
            usr = users(username, password)
            db.session.add(usr)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("User registered!")
    return render_template('register.html')


@app.route('/user')
@login_required
def user():
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('user.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash("You've just logged out!")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I need to get the current session['username'] to display it on an html template, but each time i call it and pass the argument to html through user function, like this:

```
@app.route('/user')
@login_required
def user():
    user = session['username']
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('user.html', user=user)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

it returns the last database entry of a username I've registered instead of the one that is currently logged in, can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login(), set session['Username'] = username on succesfull login

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        found_pass = users.query.filter_by(password=password).first()
        if found_user and found_pass:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['Username']=username
            flash("You've just logged in!")
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Data. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```